# Custom attributes not showing on Answers dashboard

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-fabric

I'm using Answers (Fabric) in order to have some analytics in my App but I'm having a problem with Answers dashboard in fabric.io.
When I receive an event sent from my app, I'm not able to see custom attributes tabs.

It doesn't matter if it is a custom event or not, custom attributes tabs doesn't appear. In default events (share, content view...) default tabs like *content_type* or *content_id* are shown properly.

What's happening? I have followed Fabric documentation in this way

```
 Answers.logCustomEvent(withName: "eventName", customAttributes: [
        "Custom String": "foo",
        "Custom Number": 35])
```

but it is not working at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same issue and it appears to be an ongoing system issue on their side:

> **Monitoring** - The Answers Custom Events delay is resolved for iOS, tvOS, and macOS apps. We're continuing to work through our queue of Android app events. ***Jan 4, 18:02 UTC***
>
> **Investigating** - We're currently experiencing a delay processing and displaying Answers Custom Events. The team is investigating the issue. 
>   ***Jan 4, 15:09 UTC***

Source: [Fabric Status Page](http://status.fabric.io/)

Comment: Yes, It seems a temporary issue and now is marked as Resolved. I was driving me crazy :) Thanks for the information!

Comment: Anyone else faced on 20th  August 2017 ?

Comment: Unable to see the custom attribute windows but the event has been logged